# surfaceCreated() not called after rotation

Tags: android, android-camera

My main activity presents a camera preview.  When I rotate the phone, the application closes.  In the logs, I see that surfaceCreated() and surfaceChanged() are never called after the rotation, then main’s onStop() is called.

Motorola and Samsung phones exhibit the same behavior.  The other activities in my app survive rotation as expected.

I thought the problem might be a stale Preview reference, but the logs show new holder and preview instances.

1. Why aren’t the holder callbacks being called after rotation?
2. Can I force them to be called?

Log snippet

```
07-27 08:32:12.093: I/MainActivity(21285):   
07-27 08:32:12.093: I/MainActivity(21285): ***********STARTING APP*****************
         07-27 08:32:12.093: I/MainActivity(21285): onCreate
07-27 08:32:12.093: I/MainActivity(21285):   
07-27 08:32:12.289: I/StackOPreview(21285): in constructor
07-27 08:32:12.289: V/StackOPreview(21285): holder: android.view.SurfaceView$3@4053af90
07-27 08:32:12.289: V/StackOPreview(21285): this: com.chex.camera.StackOPreview@4053aba0
07-27 08:32:12.296: I/MainActivity(21285): onCreate finished
07-27 08:32:12.296: I/MainActivity(21285):  
07-27 08:32:12.296: I/MainActivity(21285): |||||||||||||||||||   ON RESUME  |||||||||||||||||||
07-27 08:32:12.296: I/MainActivity(21285):  
07-27 08:32:12.367: I/StackOPreview(21285): surfaceCreated
07-27 08:32:12.375: I/StackOPreview(21285): view width: 540  height: 960
07-27 08:32:12.375: I/StackOPreview(21285): portrait mode so rotate camera preview
07-27 08:32:12.382: I/CameraSettings(21285): retreiving portrait orientation
07-27 08:32:12.382: I/SettingsCP(21285):  starting Settings ContentProvider query 
07-27 08:32:12.421: I/SettingsCP(21285): got 1 settings
07-27 08:32:12.421: I/CameraSettings(21285):  retrieved portrait orientation= 90
07-27 08:32:12.429: I/CameraSettings(21285):  
07-27 08:32:12.429: I/CameraSettings(21285): retreiving portrait rotation
07-27 08:32:12.429: I/SettingsCP(21285):  starting Settings ContentProvider query 
07-27 08:32:12.429: I/SettingsCP(21285): got 1 settings
07-27 08:32:12.429: I/CameraSettings(21285):  retrieved portrait rotation= 90
07-27 08:32:12.429: I/CameraSettings(21285):  
07-27 08:32:12.468: I/StackOPreview(21285): setting View measured dimensions to width: 540  height: 960
07-27 08:32:12.468: I/StackOPreview(21285): optimal preview width: 1920  height: 1080
07-27 08:32:13.929: I/StackOPreview(21285): surfaceChanged
07-27 08:32:14.085: I/StackOPreview(21285): view width: 540  height: 960
07-27 08:32:14.085: I/StackOPreview(21285): portrait mode so rotate camera preview
07-27 08:32:14.085: I/CameraSettings(21285): retreiving portrait orientation
07-27 08:32:14.085: I/SettingsCP(21285):  starting Settings ContentProvider query 
07-27 08:32:14.085: I/SettingsCP(21285): got 1 settings
07-27 08:32:14.085: I/CameraSettings(21285):  retrieved portrait orientation= 90
07-27 08:32:14.085: I/CameraSettings(21285):  
07-27 08:32:14.085: I/CameraSettings(21285): retreiving portrait rotation
07-27 08:32:14.085: I/SettingsCP(21285):  starting Settings ContentProvider query 
07-27 08:32:14.085: I/SettingsCP(21285): got 1 settings
07-27 08:32:14.093: I/CameraSettings(21285):  retrieved portrait rotation= 90
07-27 08:32:14.093: I/CameraSettings(21285):  
07-27 08:32:14.101: I/StackOPreview(21285): setting View measured dimensions to width: 540  height: 960
07-27 08:32:14.101: I/StackOPreview(21285): optimal preview width: 1920  height: 1080
07-27 08:32:27.109: I/MainActivity(21285):  
07-27 08:32:27.109: I/MainActivity(21285): |||||||||||||||||||   ON PAUSE  |||||||||||||||||||
07-27 08:32:27.109: I/MainActivity(21285):  
07-27 08:32:27.757: I/StackOPreview(21285): onPause
07-27 08:32:27.757: I/MainActivity(21285):  releasing camera in onPause
07-27 08:32:27.757: E/MainActivity(21285): onStop
07-27 08:32:27.757: I/MainActivity(21285):  
07-27 08:32:27.757: I/MainActivity(21285): |||||||||||||||||||   ON STOP  |||||||||||||||||||
```

HERE IS ROTATION START

```
07-27 08:32:27.757: I/MainActivity(21285):  
07-27 08:32:27.789: I/MainActivity(21285):   
07-27 08:32:27.789: I/MainActivity(21285): ***********STARTING APP*****************
07-27 08:32:27.789: I/MainActivity(21285): onCreate
07-27 08:32:27.789: I/MainActivity(21285):   
07-27 08:32:27.890: I/StackOPreview(21285): in constructor
07-27 08:32:27.890: V/StackOPreview(21285): holder: android.view.SurfaceView$3@40566d20
07-27 08:32:27.890: V/StackOPreview(21285): this: com.chex.camera.StackOPreview@40566930
07-27 08:32:27.898: I/MainActivity(21285): onCreate finished
07-27 08:32:27.898: I/MainActivity(21285):  
07-27 08:32:27.898: I/MainActivity(21285): |||||||||||||||||||   ON RESUME  |||||||||||||||||||


HERE IS WHERE surfaceCreated SHOULD BE CALLED

07-27 08:32:27.898: I/MainActivity(21285):  
07-27 08:32:27.945: I/MainActivity(21285):  
07-27 08:32:27.945: I/MainActivity(21285): |||||||||||||||||||   ON PAUSE  |||||||||||||||||||
07-27 08:32:27.945: I/MainActivity(21285):  
07-27 08:32:27.968: I/StackOPreview(21285): onPause
07-27 08:32:27.968: I/MainActivity(21285):  releasing camera in onPause
07-27 08:32:28.562: E/MainActivity(21285): onStop
```

Main called by Launcher

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Constants

{

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    // CameraView variables
    Camera camera;

    boolean isPreviewRunning = false;

    StackOPreview preview;

    PhotoSaver photoSaver = null;

    LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

    // first rear facing camera
    int defaultCameraId;

    // can't put big byte array in an Intent so keep a reference. This may not
    // survive pauses.
    private static byte[] currentPhoto = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.i(TAG, "  ");
        Log.i(TAG, "***********STARTING APP*****************");

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");

        Log.i(TAG, "  ");

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // Find the total number of cameras available
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        // Find the ID of the default camera. This assumes the FACING BACK
        // camera is default. probably burns us sometime.
        CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                defaultCameraId = i;
            }
        }

        camera = Camera.open(defaultCameraId);
        preview = new StackOPreview(this, camera);
        setContentView(preview);

        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate finished");

    }

    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        Log.i(TAG, " ");
        Log.i(TAG, "|||||||||||||||||||   ON RESUME  |||||||||||||||||||");
        Log.i(TAG, " ");

        if (camera == null) {
            // camera is rarely null in onResume. Either app was destroyed then
            // recreated because a long time passed, or app was just paused and
            // camera is still valid.
            camera = Camera.open(defaultCameraId);

            // July 24, 2013 sometimes preview is black - suspect it doesn't
            // have a camera
            preview.onResume(camera);

            Log.i(TAG, "OPENING camera in onResume");
        }

    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.i(TAG, " ");
        Log.i(TAG, "|||||||||||||||||||   ON PAUSE  |||||||||||||||||||");
        Log.i(TAG, " ");

        // Release camera when activity paused
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            camera = null;

            preview.onPause();

            Log.i(TAG, " releasing camera in onPause");
        }

        // close the database
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
        databaseHelper.close();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop");
        super.onStop();

        Log.i(TAG, " ");
        Log.i(TAG, "|||||||||||||||||||   ON STOP  |||||||||||||||||||");
        Log.i(TAG, " ");

        // close the database
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
        databaseHelper.close();

        finish();
    }

    /** takes the picture */
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "in CameraView.onClick");
        camera.takePicture(null, null, photoSaver);

    }

    /**
     * @return the currentPhoto
     */
    public static byte[] getCurrentPhoto() {
        return currentPhoto;
    }

    /**
     * @param currentPhoto
     *            the currentPhoto to set
     */
    public void setCurrentPhoto(byte[] currentPhoto) {
        this.currentPhoto = currentPhoto;
    }
  }
```

Preview code:

```
   public class StackOPreview extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
public Camera mCamera;

private static boolean DEBUGGING = true;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "StackOPreview";
private static final String CAMERA_PARAM_ORIENTATION = "orientation";
private static final String CAMERA_PARAM_LANDSCAPE = "landscape";
private static final String CAMERA_PARAM_PORTRAIT = "portrait";
protected Activity mActivity;

protected List<Camera.Size> previewSizeList = null;

protected Camera.Size previewSize = null;

public StackOPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);

    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"in constructor");

    mActivity = (Activity) context;
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);

    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"holder: "+mHolder);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"this: "+ this);

    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "surfaceCreated");
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the
    // preview.
    try {

        if (mCamera != null) {

            setRotationAndResolution();

            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, " camera is null");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("CameraView",
                "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "surfaceChanged");
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, " mHolder is null");
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    if (mCamera == null) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, " camera is null");

        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "failed to stopPreview because " + e, e);
    }

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        setRotationAndResolution();

        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("CameraView", "Error starting camera preview: " + e, e);
    }
}

public void onPause() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onPause");
    if (null == mCamera) {
        return;
    }

    mCamera = null;

    // try releasing
    mHolder.removeCallback(this);
}

// added July 24 2013.
/**
 * Rarely called because camera is rarely null in MainActivity's onResume().
 * Either app was destroyed then recreated because a long time passed, or
 * app was just paused and camera is still valid. Occasionally I see a black
 * screen after sleeping for a while so I added this method to try to fix
 * it.
 */
public void onResume(Camera camera) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
    mCamera = camera;
}

private void setRotationAndResolution() {
    final int width = getWidth();
    final int height = getHeight();

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "view width: " + width + "  height: " + height);

    if (height > width) {
        // PORTRAIT

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "portrait mode so rotate camera preview");

        Context context = getContext();

        int portraitOrientation = CameraSettings
                .getPortraitPreviewOrientation(context);

        int portraitRotation = CameraSettings
                .getPortraitPictureRotation(context);

        try {
            // THis line fixed the preview orientation. seems to
            // have to be called before setPreviewDisplay()
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(portraitOrientation);

            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            // this line fixes the recorded image's orientation
            parameters.setRotation(portraitRotation);

            previewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize();

            parameters
                    .setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "portrait preview settings failed: " + e, e);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "  orientation: " + portraitOrientation);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "  rotation: " + portraitRotation);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, " ");
        }

    } else {
        // LANDSCAPE

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, " landscape mode");

        int landscapeOrientation = 0;
        int landscapeRotation = 0;

        try {
            Context context = getContext();
            landscapeOrientation = CameraSettings
                    .getLandscapePreviewOrientation(context);
            landscapeRotation = CameraSettings
                    .getLandscapePictureRotation(context);

            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(landscapeOrientation);

            previewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize();

            // THis line fixed the preview orientation. seems to
            // have to be called before setPreviewDisplay()
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(landscapeOrientation);

            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

            // this line fixes the recorded image's orientation
            parameters.setRotation(landscapeRotation);

            parameters
                    .setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "landscape preview settings failed: " + e, e);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "  orientation: " + landscapeOrientation);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "  rotation: " + landscapeRotation);
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, " ");
        }
    }

}

private Size getOptimalPreviewSize() {

    // if list isn't retrieved yet, then get it
    if (previewSizeList == null) {
        previewSizeList = mCamera.getParameters()
                .getSupportedPreviewSizes();

    }

    int width = getWidth();

    int height = getHeight();

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "setting View measured dimensions to width: " + width
            + "  height: " + height);

    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio = (double) width / height;

    Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = height;

    // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
    for (Size size : previewSizeList) {
        //Log.v(LOG_TAG, "  width: " + size.width + "  height: "
            //  + size.height);

        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
            continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Size size : previewSizeList) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "optimal preview width: " + optimalSize.width
            + "  height: " + optimalSize.height);

    return optimalSize;
}
```

}

Comment: Android 2.3.3 has the problem.  Android 4.1.2 does not restart app on Galaxy S3 so problem does not occur.

Comment: added holder notification to PReview's onResume
        public void onResume(Camera camera) {
  Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
  mCamera = camera;
  mHolder = getHolder();
  mHolder.addCallback(this);
         mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
  
  Log.v(LOG_TAG,"holder: "+mHolder);
  Log.v(LOG_TAG,"this: "+ this);
 
 }

Comment: adding the holder notification had no impact

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using a tip from Mark Murphy at Commonsware.  I moved Preview create to onResume() in the main activity.  Also, I removed the finish() call in onStop().  Here is the working onCreate() and onResume() in MainActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Find the total number of cameras available
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        // Find the ID of the default camera. This assumes the FACING BACK
        // camera is default. probably burns us sometime.
        CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                defaultCameraId = i;
            }
        }
}

    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        Log.i(TAG, " ");
        Log.i(TAG, "|||||||||||||||||||   ON RESUME  |||||||||||||||||||");
        Log.i(TAG, " ");

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        camera = Camera.open(defaultCameraId);
        preview = new StackOPreview(this, camera);
        setContentView(preview);

        // *** new control layer that contains the TakePicture button ***
        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());

        viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control_preview, null);

        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

        photoSaver = new PhotoSaver(this);

        buttonTakePicture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.takepicture);

        buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(TAG,
                        "in Take Picture button on click, launching photSaver");
                camera.takePicture(null, null, photoSaver);
            }
        });

        // table button
        Button tableButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.display_table);

        TableButtonListener tableButtonListener = new TableButtonListener(this);
        tableButton.setOnClickListener(tableButtonListener);
    }
```